# Boundary conditions for an FEM approximation of the Laplace operator

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, approximation

Using FEM, I want to approximate the Laplacian

$$u = \nabla \cdot \nabla h \, ,$$

where $h(x,y)$ is an FEM approximated scalar field on the same mesh, i.e. piecewise differentiable.

I am using [MOOSE](https://mooseframework.inl.gov/) to solve the following (hopefully correct!) weak formulation of the above equation:

$$\int_\Omega uw_i \, \text{d}\Omega = -\int_\Omega \nabla h \cdot  \nabla w_i \, \text{d}\Omega + \int_\Gamma \nabla h \cdot \vec{n}w_i \, \text{d}\Gamma \,,$$

where $w_i$ is the i-th test function and $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector on the boundary $\Gamma$ of the computational domain $\Omega$. I am not using any boundary conditions on $u$.

The FEM solution that I obtain for this weak formulation is inaccurate at the boundaries (see below). I have tested this by prescribing the field $h=\text{sin}(x)$ on a 2D rectangular domain from $-2\pi \le x \le 2\pi$
and solving with quadratic Lagrange shape functions for both $h$ and $u$. (it is also inaccurate using linear shape functions, but it is easier to spot with quadratic shape functions).

**Is it possible to obtain an accurate $u$ at the boundaries with this approach? Am I missing a boundary condition/contribution?**

[image: h(x) = sin(x)]
[image: FEM solution for u]

---

**Background:**

I am dealing with a thin film approximation of the Navier-Stokes equations in 2D FEM, where the film height is modeled by a dependent variable $h(x,y)$. In order to include surface tension as a contribution to the pressure gradient, I want to find the curvature of the film surface $u(x,y)$ that I approximate by the second derivative

$u \approx \nabla \cdot \nabla h$ .

My idea is to introduce curvature $u$ as a variable, solve the above equation by FEM, and couple $u$ into the momentum equation.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you want to achieve. You have a function $h(x, y)$ and you want to compute it's Laplacian over a domain?

Comment: Are you ignoring the boundary term from your weak form? The formulation you have should show up with a Neumann boundary term for GFEM.

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes, but let me reformulate: I want to calculate u by FEM so that it approximates the Laplacian of h(x, y) ("source term" on the right hand side of the equation). I don't have a closed form of h(x, y) though, because it is actually a variable in another FEM problem.

Comment: @wwfe Can you tell me what boundary term you mean and what it should look  like? I don't have a boundary term with u since I am not integrating by parts on the LHS of the pde.

Comment: @pimpom the boundary represented by the integral over $\Gamma$ is in your equation, just because u isn't there doesn't mean it isn't a boundary term, it is still part of the residual.

Comment: @wwfe Then the answer to your question is no, I am not ignoring the boundary term on the rhs of the weak formulation as I wrote it. But what do you mean by "[the formulation] should show up with a Neumann boundary term"?

Comment: @wwfe At the boundary, $\nabla h$ is known. I calculate its perpendicular component through the boundary, multiply by the test function and add this to the residual of the elements at the boundaries. Isn't this already the Neumann boundary term you mean?

Comment: @pimpom sorry I misspoke when I said Neumann but yes that is the term I was talking about. I would double check signs on that boundary term to make sure they match the rest of your equation. If you are just using simple forms for h I would say it would be better to compute $u$ directly. However I'm assuming you have a reason to be doing it this way.

Comment: @wwfe Thanks for your help! I have checked the signs with no success. I might need to check the FEM implementation then.